# How to modify this code so that it support array return value?

Tags: java

```
public Solution getReferenceSolution(Problem p)
        throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        Solution result;

        if (!haveReferenceSolution)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Domain.getReferenceSolution: A getReferenceSolution() method has not been specified for this domain.  If its use is required, please specify one using setEquivalenceClasses() or by overriding Domain.getReferenceSolution().");
        else {
            if (haveBooleanSolutionCutoff)
                result = findNearestEquivalenceClass(p).applyTo(p, booleanSolutionCutoff);
            else
                result = findNearestEquivalenceClass(p).applyTo(p);
        }

        result.setIsReferenceSolution(true);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain more precisely what you expect to have in returned array.

Comment: I am having 2 types of classes. One class use this class to return non-array result. For another class, i want to use this class to return an array result. eg: Solution[] . How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
public Solution[] getReferenceSolution(Problem p) {
    Solution result;
    // set result.
    return new Solution[] { result };
}
```

Comment: this function is referred by other classes too. but those classes dont need array. How can I somehow override this function just for one class that want to return array?

Comment: how to declare it as an override?

Comment: The return types need to be the same for all implementations (or a sub class). Either you use an array to return on all of them or none of them.  Another option is to have a Solution which contains an array of Solution. This would allow you to return an "array" inside a Solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one solution normally, but one place needs multiple solutions, I suggest you have two methods; something like this:

```
public Solution getReferenceSolution(Problem p)
{
    // Code as before
}

public List<Solution> getAllSolutions(Problem p)
{
    // Whatever you need to do here
}
```

Note how it's now obvious from the method name whether you're looking for one solution or multiple ones; I wouldn't use overloading in this situation, as you're trying to do different things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better to return a collection, e.g. an `ArrayList`:

```
public List<Solution> getReferenceSolution(Problem p)
    throws UnsupportedOperationException {

    List<Solution> solutions= new ArrayList<Solution>();

    Solution result = ... // your code here

    solutions.add(result);

    return solutions;
}
```

Or maybe you want to pass the `List` as argument to the `getReferenceSolution` method and fill it inside the method?

```
public void getReferenceSolution(Problem p, List<Solution> solutions)
    throws UnsupportedOperationException {

    // your code to fill the list using solutions.add(Solution)

}
```